# Uploading file using Google Drive API returns "400: Bad Request"

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to upload a file to Google Drive using the Google Drive API and Java.

The file I'm trying to upload is a docx file (previously exported using the Drive API). My problem is that when uploading files that has filenames containing swedish characters (like åäö), the Drive API throws an exception.

The code for uploading looks essentially like this:

```
File file = new File("/path/to/file.docx");
String contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";

File fileToUpload = new File()
            .setTitle("abc")
            .setMimeType(contentType);

FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(contentType, file);

try {
    Drive.Files.Insert request = client.files().insert(fileToUpload, mediaContent);
    request.execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("Could not restore file");
    throw e;
}
```

This code actually works fine. *But* if I change setTitle("abc") to setTitle("abcö") I get this exception:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
Bad Request
```

I have tried using versions v2-rev82-1.14.2-beta and v2-rev82-1.15.0-rc of google-api-services-drive, with the same result.

I am using OSX if that helps (Windows seems to have these kinds of problems more often).

---

EDIT:
After some experimenting I found that if I exclude the FileContent object (the actual file content), and only create an empty file uploading the meta data, then the swedish characters in the title are fine.

```
Drive.Files.Insert request = client.files().insert(fileToUpload);
```

Seems like it's not the title that's the main problem after all. If I just can figure out how to add the file data to the empty file, I should be done.

---

### EDIT2: Solution found!

Adding: `request.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(true);` enables direct upload (not sure what I was using before though), and apparently that makes Google Drive not care about my strange Swedish characters anymore (Again, not sure why).

This is the code I ended up with (with simplifications):

```
File file = new File("/path/to/file.docx");
String contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";

File fileToUpload = new File()
        .setTitle("abcö")
        .setMimeType(contentType);

FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(contentType, file);

try {
    Drive.Files.Insert request = client.files().insert(fileToUpload, mediaContent);
    request.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(true);
    request.execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("Could not restore file");
    throw e;
}
```

Now I only need to add support for resumable uploads for big files, but that's a different story.

EDIT3: By the way, [here are the docs](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/MediaUpload) that got me on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode it as UTF-8, or change the uploadType to "media".

Comment: Tried UTF-8, same error.

Can't see how to change the uploadType. The [official docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads) are not entirely clear on how to do this using the Java api.

Comment: Ok, so now I managed to solve the problem.

Adding this line before execute does the trick:

    request.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(true);

I guess that this is the same thing as 'changing the uploadType to "media"'?